# What is the difference between Euclid's division lemma and Euclid's division algorithm?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

My textbook claims that Euclid's division algorithm depends upon Euclid's division lemma but can you elaborate?

Comment: What does Euclid's lemma say?

Comment: I'm assuming your book has these definitions, so best to write them down as a start, and then show where you are stuck seeing how one depends on the other.

Comment: Also in general, someone may not know Euclid's division lemma or Euclid's division algorithm, but when written up in your question they may then be able to work out what's going on and give you an answer straight off, without them having to research the lemma and the algorithm firsthand, so creating a lot of extra research time.

Comment: The terms I usually see in the textbooks are Euclid's Algorithm (which finds the gcd of two numbers) and the Division Algorithm (which isn't actually an algorithm, it's a theorem, the one that says for $a,b$ integers, $b\ne0$, there exist unique integers $q,r$ such that $a=bq+r$ and $0\le r<|b|$). The former depends on the latter in that the former is achieved by repeated application of the latter.

Comment: It is worth mention that there are many versions of the "Euclidean algorithm" for the gcd, and not all (explicitly) employ the division algorithm. The original algorithm in Euclid's *Elements* used anthyphairesis (reciprocal subtraction, i.e. continually subtract the smaller from the larger). There is a also a binary version, and quasilinear variations for huge numbers, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Euclid's Division Lemma states: for $a$, $b\in\mathbb{Z}$, $b\ne0$, there exist unique $q$, $r\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that
$$a=qb+r, \qquad 0\le r<|b|\tag{$\star$}$$
We call $q$ the quotient, and $r$ the remainder. The lemma itself can be proved by induction on $a$. Euclid's Division Algorithm is an algorithm to find the greatest common divisor ($\gcd$) of two natural numbers facilitated by repeated use of the Division Lemma until in the last use of $(\star)$ we get a zero remainder and the process terminates with the $\gcd$ given by the last non-zero remainder. Each time the Division Lemma is invoked in the Division Algorithm, the new $a$ and $b$ are the preceding steps $b$ and $r$ respectively.

For example to find $\gcd(267,126)$ the Division Algorithm takes four steps to get to a zero-remainder, each step a usage of the Division Lemma:

- Step 1: Find the remainder when $267$ is divided by $126$. By Euclid's Division Lemma with $a_1=267$, $b_1=126$, we have
  $$267=2\times126+15\tag{1}$$
  and so $q_1=2$,  $r_1=15$.
- Step 2: Find the remainder when $126$ is divided by $15$. By Euclid's Division Lemma with $a_2=126$, $b_2=15$, we have
  $$126=8\times15+6\tag{2}$$
  and so $q_2=8$, and $r_2=6$.
- Step 3: Find the remainder when $15$ is divided by $6$. By Euclid's Division Lemma with $a_3=15$, $b_3=6$, we have
  $$15=2\times6+3\tag{3}$$
  and so $q_3=2$,  $r_3=3$.
- Step 4: Find the remainder when $6$ is divided by $3$. By Euclid's Division Lemma with $a_4=6$, $b_4=3$, we have
  $$6=2\times3+0\tag{4}$$
  and so $q_4=2$,  $r_4=0$. Here the Division Algorithm terminates since $r_4=0$, and $\gcd(267,126)=r_3=3$ is the last non-zero remainder from Step 3.

Answer (score 2):

Putting it simply,

Euclid's Division Lemma is the statement that any non negative integer $n$ can be expressed in $n=aq+b$ form where $0\leq b<q$.

Division algorithm is a method to compute the Greatest Common Divisor of two numbers which is based on repeated application of Euclid's Divsion Lemma until the remainder comes out to be $0$.